# Get Element via this with length instead of event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have a general question regarding jQuery.

I know that if you use an event handler like click, you can select the affected element within the function via the selector "this".

In a current project I use a lot of "if element exists" checks via length

```
if($('#formButton_cc input').length) {
    do sth..
}
```

Is there any way to select the corresponding element, in this case "#formButton_cc input", within the function via something like "this", without having to write it again or storing it in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('#formButton_cc input').each(function () {
    var val = this.value;
});
```

Comment: So I can use each() as an element "existence" check like length()?

Comment: Pretty much, it won't go through with the  each if there are no elements